# append bookmarklet functionality to URL

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

[This article](http://nerdgap.com/how-bookmarklets-work-and-how-to-make-your-own/) teaches me how to make a simple bookmarklet. Pretty straightfoward. Basically write some javascript and add `void(0)` at the end. I have a bookmark I use frequently that has a link which downloads a Java app that needs frequently to be **re**downloaded. Is there a way to add a bookmarklet to the the end of that bookmark so that I can go there, and also attach a `document.getElementById("java_app_link").click()` to the end to automatically download it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that but you will need to include jQuery in the JavaScript if you want to use `.click()`

Comment: @Alex W  Isn't click a native JavaScript method?

Comment: No. It is a jQuery method. Natively, you would have to use event handling (e.g. `fireEvent` or `dispatchEvent`) to simulate a click.

Comment: @AlexW Why does this work then? http://jsbin.com/UrUcoma/1/

Comment: It works because it is an `input` element. [The standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361) only defines that method on `input` elements, but your `java_app_link` implies that it is an `a` element. Also, I don't believe older versions of IE support `.click()` natively.

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript: window.location.href = 'http://example.com'; window.onload = function(){document.getElementById("java_app_link").click()}; void(0);
```

This is kind of a hack and may not be possible in the future. It works only if you use CTRL+click on the bookmark and works only in Chrome.

Otherwise create a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript). The most simple userscripts are just like bookmarklets that run automatically. Below is an example.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Script Name
// @namespace   ScriptName
// @description download java app
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @include     http://example.com
// ==/UserScript==
document.getElementById("java_app_link").click()
```